# What program should designers use to modify asp.net MVC views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, process

I'm getting our company to switch from a classic asp, dreamweaver based design/develop workflow to a ASP.NET MVC based design develop workflow.

Is it recommended that designers use Visual Studio to edit Master pages and views? I'm thinking that it is ok because they might need to edit a config file or a controller along the way. However, if there is a different "Best Practices" method/workflow then I'm all ears.

Comment: Are your designers also programmers?

Comment: SLaks - Currently aspx - however Razr looks really cool and we'll probably be updating our CMS to use it in the future.

Comment: mellamokb - So far, we've trained our design department to be hybrids... they don't have deep programming know-how, but they are able to take a site from start to finish and do small modifications when needed.

Comment: Your designers will appreciate razor, as it gets in the way a lot less and lets the base markup of the page be that much more obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our designers use Visual Studio 2010 for editing our MVC 3 views. It took a couple days of meetings to just go over all the information they needed to know, plus we're here to help them if they have questions. We're on a team of 4 (2 programmers, 2 designers) and we're all plugged in to TFS 2010, which is another reason to have them on Visual Studio.

There's no reason any designer worth their salary shouldn't be able to figure out how to use Visual Studio for editing markup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the user doing the design work will never get a preview of what the view looks like without actually running the app. So basically they just need a good text editor, and Visual Studio is just as good as any here.

The nice thing is you can alter a view at runtime and refresh the page and you'll see your changes, which leads to a pretty efficient `do markup -> refresh` development loop.

Comment: I agree Studio is the answer, although it is so so slow switching between Design and Source mode, especially 2010!

Comment: @Jonathan : Using Design view in MVC doesn't make much sense, so it is not the problem here.

Comment: is design mode even an option? At least for me using razor views I have no designer options at all. Perhaps webform views allow this?

Comment: With MVC, certainly you can view the design, not sure with Razor though ... but it wont actually be a browser view which I think @LukLed may be refering to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others here that Visual Studio is the way to go but if there's some reason you don't want to use Visual Studio then [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) maybe an alternative option in the future, but it currently only supports Razor views.  It's underrated as a quick and simple way of editing Views, HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc.